# Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I am new to react and am getting the following error:

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

I am trying to import a component to app.js and am getting this error:

Here is my app.js:

```
import "./App.css";
import Header from "./Header";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      
      <Header />
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is my header component:

```
import React from 'react'

function Header()  {
    return (
        <div className="header">
        <h1>I am a header</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Header
```

Why am I getting this error and how to solve it.

Here is the error:

[image]

Comment: You may need to import `react` into the `App` component for JSX to work. What version of React are you using?

Comment: That import doesnt work I am using 17.0.2 react

Comment: I think Import should work import React from 'react';
Have a look here https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hqla2z?file=src%2FApp.js
It's using the same version as mentioned.

Comment: No that import is not working may be there is some other error

Comment: do we extend to react component like in class components?

Comment: @Sam You still need to import `React` in your index.js, see this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/error-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string-for-built-in-components-or-a-7cd66). I copy/pasted your code, it works without issue once `React` is imported. If you ***are*** importing `React` there then the issue m***must*** because by some other code you've not included in your snippets. What is `reportWebVitals`? What else is imported, used, or rendered in `App`? Please include a more comprehensive code example.